# How I can to export a chart, when charts are in a datatable? Primefaces 3.4

Tags: jsf, primefaces, charts, datatable, export

What is idea?

1. Save the graphics in images.
2. Pass the binary to a String on the server.
3. Identify the graph from the binary (ready).
4. Create a pdf with data and graphics (ready, use itex).
5. View the pdf (ready).

But I can not export any graphics. This is because I can not detect them.
When I include a graphic in a datatable, widgetvar are repeated, so I can not use the solution of the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chartExport.jsf).

```
$('#output').empty().append(chartWidgetvar.exportAsImage());
```

This is part of my code.

```
<h:form id="reportePro">
<p:dataTable value="#{listas.reporteSeccionPro}" var="p"
      selection="#{listas.reporteSeleccionadoSeccionPro}"
      selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{p.idFila}"
      emptyMessage="No existen coincidencias" id="reporteGeneral">
      <p:column headerText="Chart">
         <p:commandButton id="chartBtn" value="Gráficos" type="button" />
         <p:overlayPanel id="chartPanel" for="chartBtn" hideEffect="fade"
            showEffect="fade" appendToBody="true"
            style="width:900px;height:450px;">
            <p:pieChart id="pie" 
               styleClass="jqplot-table-legend jqplot-target"
               value="#{p.pieModel}" extender="ext"
               title="#{p.nomProSeccionPro}"
               style="width:400px;height:450px;font-size:15px;"
               showDataLabels="true" sliceMargin="5"
               seriesColors="DB4C14, C0E9ED, A8CCED, C7B47F, F7F28F, 4DB0C4" />
         </p:overlayPanel>
      </p:column>
   </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

I thought use dynamic id ,

```
<p:pieChart id="#{chart.idPie}"  />
```

but can not be set.

I thought use dynamic widgetvar,

```
<p:pieChart widgetvar="#{chart.idPie}"  />
```

but can not be set.

I thought of using only the id of the graphics,

```
#{p:widgetVar ('ComponentId')}
```

but remember that you can not use dynamic id

Another solution might be to use the canvas.toDataURL, for that, I need the id of the first canvas, but does not generate primefaces ID.
So I can not use this solution.

After spending hours and did not find the solution, I ask me.
It is possible to export a chart to an image, when they are in a datatable?